# Change MTU Programmatically with C#

Tags: c#

I want to change MTU value for windows 7/8.1/10 with C#.

I tried to search on Stack Overflow but only netsh is what I can find.

1. Get current MTU value
2. Set custom MTU value

I don't want to use any cmd commands, any idea to do with C# only?

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ Quite the contrary – netsh is generally a "proxy" (interface really) for the underlying Win32 APIs, and if netsh can talk those APIs, so can C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the WMI API for this.

There's a [Visual Basic example](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/49c26363-d46c-4288-9c8d-feb0a1982998) you can probably adapt:

```
On Error Resume Next 

strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _ 
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

Set objNetworkSettings = objWMIService.Get("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration") 
objNetworkSettings.SetMTU(68)
```

The [`SetMTU` method is documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/setmtu-method-in-class-win32-networkadapterconfiguration), and the C# APIs to talk with WMI [are documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/wmi_v2/how-to-implement-a-managed-mi-client).